# Firebase, Angularfire, Cloud Endpoints - New user registration occasionally results in a duplicate user

Tags: python, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

Firebase-auth.js (3.5.2)
Appengine Python
Google Cloud Endpoints

My login process works great most of the time, but occasionally, a duplicate user account is created.  They are timestamped milliseconds apart. I have attempted to put checks in the JS to prevent the duplicates, but I'm still occasionally seeing duplicates.

I opened a support ticket with firebase.  They instructed me to post the question here instead.

The clientConnect endpoint is where the user is created if it does not already exist.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
    // We are getting duplicate user registrations sometimes because of the way firebase spams refreshes on the page.
    // Trying to isolate so only one request happens at a time.
    var checkAuthenticationInProgress = false;

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      console.log('app.js - onAuthStateChanged')
      if (user) {
        console.log('onAuthStateChanged - user found')
        user.getToken().then(function(idToken) {
          userIdToken = idToken;
          $http.defaults.headers.common['X-UETOPIA-Auth'] = 'Bearer ' + userIdToken;
          checkEndpointsAuthentication();
    }}}

    checkEndpointsAuthentication = function() {
      if (userIdToken) {
        if (!checkAuthenticationInProgress) {
          checkAuthenticationInProgress = true;
          endpoints.post('users', 'clientConnect', {})  
              .then(function(response) {
                  // DONE!
                  console.log(response);
                  if (response.refresh_token) {
                    console.log('Firebase Unauth - REFRESHING');
                    console.log(firebase.auth());

                  }
                  setTimeout(resetCheckAuthenticationInProgress(), 2000);
              }, function() {
                // ERROR!
                console.log('error');
                setTimeout(resetCheckAuthenticationInProgress(), 2000);
              });
        } else {
          console.log('already checking auth - retrying');
          setTimeout(checkEndpointsAuthentication(), 2000);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('no userIdToken found - skipping');
      }
    };

    // I think it is being reset too quickly in some cases.

    resetCheckAuthenticationInProgress = function() {
      checkAuthenticationInProgress = false;
    }
```

Comment: How do you define and use checkAuthenticationInProgress? More detail on the code fragment will surely prove useful.

Comment: It's just a bool.
var checkAuthenticationInProgress = false;

Comment: Is there any improvement if you set the timeout to a different value? 

It may be possible to alter the strategy altogether and manage concurrent login requests, by allowing different user authentication at an a minimum interval from one another. You can determine a minimum delay value, that never allows users to login too soon. In this way, no resulting duplicate accounts occur.

Comment: Thanks for the response George.  Changing the timeout interval has no effect.   As far as I can tell, the issue is at least partially caused by the way firebase-ui spams refreshes on the page when logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that the `onAuthStateChanged` callback is called once the user logs in, and then again on the page redirected to by `signInSuccessUrl` (the same page, in this case).

You can either use the [signInSuccess callback](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#signinsuccesscurrentuser-credential-redirecturl) (called before the final refresh), or [not use the Firebase UI library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin).

Keep in mind that if you are trying to capture only the initial sign-up, then both `onAuthStateChanged` and `signInSuccess` will trigger on every login.  You'll have to check that the user was just created, or do some deduplication on your server to prevent duplicate users on future logins.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I implemented your suggestion, but since it is an intermittent issue, I'll need to wait to verify that it solves the issue.

Comment: Just a quick follow up.  This did work.  I have not seen any duplicates.